# threadIdx.x value in CUDA is always starting from 0?

Tags: cuda

I am using CUDA to image processing, and I need to know which is the first thread (the first pixel), but there is a chance that if I call kernel function with less than maximum possible threads, there will be no thread 0. I could not found any documentation. Is someone sure about this question?

Comment: BTW IIRC the maximum threadIdx.x number can be higher, as always whole warps (groups of 32 threads) are started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the numbering always starts at zero.

`threadIdx.x` is a built-in variable for CUDA device code/kernel code.

each threadblock in your kernel launch is guaranteed to have at least one thread that has a `threadIdx.x` value of zero.

In the case of a multi-dimensional threadblock, it's possible for more than one thread in each threadblock to have a `threadIdx.x` value of 0.  (In that case, either `threadIdx.y` or `threadIdx.z`, or both, will vary amongst that group.)

Generally speaking, threads are numbered consecutively from zero up to the number of threads in the block, taking into account multi-dimensional (i.e. ordered pair, etc.) numbering in the case of multi-dimensional blocks.

This is covered in some detail in the [cuda programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#thread-hierarchy).

The above statements apply to CUDA C++ and Python bindings (such as pycuda, numba cuda, and cupy).  [CUDA Fortran numbering](https://docs.nvidia.com/hpc-sdk/pgi-compilers/19.5/x86/cuda-fortran-prog-guide/index.htm#cfpg-thread-blocks) begins at 1.